# What is the best caching design for sequential data?

Tags: asp.net, caching, azure

I am selling tickets online, each tickets has ticket key(32bytes random)  and ticket id(long sequential). I have 2 types of customer small who asks around 1-10k keys and wholesaler asking 50k-1m tickets, whole salers wants tickets ids to be sequential as possible.I should not sell same ticket to 2 customers.Tickets are generate and put in sql db and I can pull/save at front ends(azure instances) and this is what I am planning. At the front end machines what caching I should use that I can both read/mark in sequential atomic way and also I can use among asp.net requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing solution on Windows Azure, Windows Azure Cache is your best option to use. It is fast when "Local Caching" is enabled as latency will be almost 0ms but you data must fit in memory. You can find more info on Windows Azure Cache [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx).

If you want to try Memcached, you sure can try however with Memcached and "Windows Azure cache with local caching", there is not much difference you will see. SMarx has a great article on using Memcache on Windows Azure [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/memcached-in-windows-azure).

I think you can use [SQLCacheDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx) class to create a cache item dependency on a with the ticket item in database. When a ticket is taken by agent, the ticket item row will change which will cause the  dependency invalidated and ticket ID will be from the cache.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957907.aspx) is pattern and practice Guide for .NET Framework Applications which can guide you to write better ways to cache the content for atomic access.

I would suggest you to take a look here as well: 
[What Are the Patterns and Best Practices for Caching in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763694/what-are-the-patterns-and-best-practices-for-caching-in-asp-net)