# C#: what are keys when talking about cache

Tags: c#, caching, key

I don't have a lot of experience with c sharp. I was assigned to implement a cacheing feature. I am looking over some of the code and I have no idea what "key" and "dependsOnKey" is referring to.

```
        public void Add(string key, object o, DateTimeOffset expiration, string dependsOnKey = null)
    {
        var cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = expiration
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dependsOnKey))
        {
            cachePolicy.ChangeMonitors.Add(
                Cache.CreateCacheEntryChangeMonitor(new[] { dependsOnKey })
            );
        }
        lock (Cache)
        {
            Cache.Add(key, o, cachePolicy);
        }
    }

    public void Add(string key, object o, string dependsOnKey = null)
    {
        DateTimeOffset dt = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(20);

        Add(key, o, dt, dependsOnKey);
    }
```

In the context of cache, what does key mean? I understand what the concept of caching. I looked up some tutorials but most have different implementation of caching.

Comment: If you cache something you need to give it an identifier so that when you want to read it, you provide that identifier in order to get it. You need to know which key opens which door or you'll be lost.

Comment: so the key  has similar functionality compared to the key in a key value pair? can I give the key any name I want or is there a convention to naming keys? I assume that means keys have to be unique then.

Comment: Side note: interesting choice of first assignment... You know that caching in [one of two hard things](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html):"there are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov well it's not my first assignment. I got bored with doing the same controller/service/api stuff so I kind of requested a challenge. =X
can you elaborate as to what cache invalidation is and why it is difficult?

Answer (score 1):

Simply, it is the a string identifier than you can you somewhere else to read the same data aka : `Cache.Get Method (String key)`

More in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx)

Be aware that:

> Items in the application cache are stored in key/value pairs. Key
>   dependency allows an item to be dependent on the key of another item
>   in the application cache. When the original item is removed, the item
>   that has the key dependency is also removed. For example, you could
>   add a cache item named ReportsValid, and then cache several reports
>   that are dependent on the ReportsValid key. When the ReportsValid item
>   is removed, all the dependent cached reports are similarly removed
>   from the cache.

Also, it is worth looking at: [What Are the Patterns and Best Practices for Caching in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763694/what-are-the-patterns-and-best-practices-for-caching-in-asp-net)